# getBitmap from SQLite to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, bitmap

I'm trying to show profile `Contact` image from `SQLite` on android app but it doesn't work and it crashes on `image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` that appears `.NullPointerException` and I don't Know why.

If someone can help me please. this is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = database.query("amigos", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
    data.moveToFirst();
    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_def, data, fields, new int[] {R.id.Nombre_Amigo, R.id.profile_picture});

    Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....data: "+data.toString());

        while (!data.isAfterLast()){    
            byte[] bb = data.getBlob(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_PIC_SQ));
            Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....bb: "+bb.toString());
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
            Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....inputStream: "+inputStream.toString());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
            Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....Bitmap: "+bitmap.toString());
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....image: "+image.toString());
        }

    Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....datasource: "+dataSource.toString());      
    setListAdapter(dataSource);
    Log.d("ListarContactos","Oncreate....despres del ListAdapter");     
    helper.close();
    ListView view = getListView();
}
```

Comment: You are testing the app in emulator or device?

Comment: you must call setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout) before try to use findViewById() method , in your case your (image ) is null ,,,ie should pass the layout in setContentView where the imageView id used R.id.profile_picture

Comment: on emulator, this is important? after I wanna test on device.

Comment: another important thing is that I'm using ListActivity

Comment: As i understand `R.id.profile_picture` is in `Item View` so you can't find it in current activity. Create `custom Adapter` and get image data in `getView`

Comment: can I get image and contact name on the same custom Adapter or I must have two custom Adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throws `nullPointerException` because method  `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length)` return `NULL` to Bitmap.